# how to insert a char after specified number

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I want to insert a | after a specified number of characters on every line, then remove trailing whitespace.
For example...

Insert a | on characters 11, 15, 27, and 46 of every line. Then remove trailing white space before each |

```
1234567890 123 blahblahblah              blahblahblah
```

into

```
1234567890|123|blahblahblah|blahblahblah
```

Comment: positions like 11,15 etc are they always empty?

Comment: They are always empty. I could make use of William's except that sometimes I have addresses which are separated by a space. If I could say "between chars 100 and 120, replace spaces between words with a %" then run awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=\|, then turn all "%" into spaces again, that would be perfect. But I don't know how use a reg ex only between places 100 and 120.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to count characters, or do you just want:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=\|
```

Comment: That's elegant... Thanks! Can you tell me how I would have counted chars though?

Comment: Here's one way: `perl -pe 'for $x(11,15,27,46) { substr( $_, $x, 0, "|")} s/\s+\|/|/g'`  This also replaces whitespace before non-inserted `|`, but that's easy to fix.

Comment: This does exactly what I want it to. Thanks.